# Java function to transfer data between lists?

Tags: java, list, transfer

I am trying to make a poker game and would like to transfer data between my ArrayList "deck" and have another list "hand". I have hard-coded my list to include all 52 cards in a standard deck and want to pop the first card off of the list deck to the list hand by referencing the location of the card in the deck. Due to shuffling the deck I can't reference the name of the card to transfer it and just need the location of the card to transfer to the hand. Does anyone know a function to do this, a way to hard-code this or even where to look. I can clarify anything if needed.

Comment: which is it?  you say both the _first_ card, and some card by index.

Comment: Well I need the first card so that I can deal the first card of the deck, remove the reference to the card in the deck and then reference the new first card of the deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `hand` and `deck` are of type `ArrayList<Card>` then it's simply:

```
hand.add(deck.remove(0));
```

Note that `ArrayList` isn't a particularly good class for this, as it's not designed for efficient removal of entries other than at the end of the list.

Comment: I'm new to Java, how would you apply hand and deck to one ArrayList?

Comment: @user1174711 you probably wouldn't, they'd be separate lists.

Comment: +1 Easy and straightforward. Though I disagree with the efficiency consideration. Performance may be a consideration if you're writing a poker server like Zynga's. For a Java n00b best to keep it simple. @user1174711: If you find this answer useful don't forget to accept it. That's how the site works. And welcome to SO.

Comment: I'm writing the game for a personal project so performance is not really an issue. Also thank you for the welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier if you store your deck of cards in an [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).  By doing that you could call `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the deck and as you're dealing just `pop` the next card off the deck, er, `Deque`.

Comment: I am looking into this suggestion. It looks quite promising. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) for the deck since that is how card deck operates and it does indeed "pop" the first object out of the collection. (You could also use the [generic Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html) for a more modern, type-safe approach and you implementation could still be a list collection.)

Here's some info on [shuffling a Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467244/java-knuth-shuffle-on-a-stack). A shuffled Stack then behaves exactly like a card deck.

Comment: Why not pass the `Stack` to `Collections.shuffle`? `Stack` is based on `Vector` - take a look at `ArrayDeque` for a non-synchronized alternative. (new as of 1.6).

Comment: I am currently using Collections.shuffle on my ArrayList. What if any benefit of using a stack for this?

Comment: The benefit is that a Stack already works like a deck. It models the real world for you out-of-the box so you have to write less logic to manage an ArrayList to behave like a deck. @Paul: That's what the shuffling a Stack link suggests.

Comment: Funnily enough, a `Deque` also works like a deck. Or a stack, as the API says, "This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack."

Comment: What's up with the down vote? Is it fair to say that with a collection of 52 objects either deck-like collection will do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29). It returns the object at index and removes it from the list.